# How to use django-haystack with django-machina and SQLite?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, sqlite, django-haystack

I'm using django-machina as forum app and it has django-haystack integration in the box which is great, but I don't need to setup Sorl or Whoosh yet, the client asked to use SQLite for beginning. However when I'm trying to search ANYTHING in search form, I receive such SQL query:

```
SELECT forum_conversation_post.id,  forum_conversation_post.created,  forum_conversation_post.updated,  forum_conversation_post.topic_id,  forum_conversation_post.poster_id,
forum_conversation_post.poster_ip,  forum_conversation_post.anonymous_key,  forum_conversation_post.subject,  forum_conversation_post.content,  forum_conversation_post.username,  forum_conversation_post.approved,  forum_conversation_post.enable_signature,  forum_conversation_post.update_reason,  forum_conversation_post.updated_by_id, forum_conversation_post.updates_count,  forum_conversation_post._content_rendered FROM forum_conversation_post WHERE (forum_conversation_post.anonymous_key LIKE '%[1]>%' ESCAPE '\' OR forum_conversation_post.subject LIKE '%[1]>%' ESCAPE '\' OR forum_conversation_post.content LIKE '%[1]>%' ESCAPE '\' OR forum_conversation_post.username LIKE '%[1]>%' ESCAPE '\' OR forum_conversation_post.update_reason LIKE '%[1]>%' ESCAPE '\' OR forum_conversation_post._content_rendered LIKE '%[1]>%' ESCAPE '\') ORDER BY forum_conversation_post.created ASC
```

In short, it just changes any search phrase to "[1]>" string on the SQL level.

I've spent many hours tying to figure out what's wrong with it, but can't understand why does it happen and how to solve the issue.

Comment: just checked it with PostgreSQL - it's the same issue.